# how to write on google cloud storage from instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a bucket and edited permission for the instance user/alluser, but can not write on the bucket folder.I am getting error as below-

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://console.cloud.google.com/....

Comment: How are you trying to write to it?

Comment: Can you specify the way you're trying to write to the bucket? If you're just trying to write to a GCP Bucket from inside a GCP VM Instance or Cloud Shell you can use command 'gsutil cp <your-text-file-to-copy>  gs://<your-bucket>'. Just make sure you are either in the directory where <your-text-file-to-copy> is or specify its path. You can follow documentation [1] which provide more information about the different options available with this command. [1]:https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: I am running a script on instance for scrapping data from website and want to write on bucket at the same time.

Comment: I've just performed a test to copy a file from a GCE instance to a GCS Bucket by running the CLI command [1] as explained in the documentation and I was able to perform the action.

You can find this quickstart [3] useful.

Can you describe the procedure you are following?


[1] $ gsutil cp config.yaml gs://example-bucket
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp
[3] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil

Comment: I am using this command, gsutil - cp -r /home/mydirectory  gs://shopstyle-visual-search-server/shopstyle. But I have 9million images to transfer from instance to bucket, which will take years. Any faster method?

Comment: If you have a large number of files to transfer you might want to use the gsutil -m option, to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy:
gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my-bucket
The source document where you can find thin info is this one: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp